# How to sort and store data on another spreadsheet in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

0I have a dynamic list with data which I have to sort. In the list there are 5 different location identifiers, each location has 2 or 3 results that need to be carried over.

```
LocationID  Date       Result*1  Result*2  Result *3
*001        12-3-2018   1           1           4
*002        13-3-2018   8           0           2
*003        14-3-2018   9           0           4
*004        15-3-2018   10          0           0
*005        16-3-2018   5           0           3
*001        17-3-2018   6           2           3
*002        18-3-2018   2           0           3

etc.
```

I want to separate this into several columns in which the first four columns are grouped under *001 and has the date and the 3 results.

I tried using vlookup, but it doesn't handle the duplicates in locations.
I also tried using the advanced filter function, but I don't get it to work properly on a dynamic sheet.

**Edit:**
The result I want is that I get a new spreadsheet in which I have the data sorted in columns with the location identifier at the top on the row below Date, Result*1, Result*2 and Result*3. I also want to be able to select which results get transferred to the new spreadsheet. For location *002 Result*2 is irrelevant, so I want to omit it from the overview. I wish for it to look something like the following.

```
*001                                            *002            
Date        Result *1   Result *2   Result *3   Date        Result *1   Result *3   
12-3-2018   1           1           4           13-3-2018   8           2    
17-3-2018   6           2           3           18-3-2018   2           3
22-3-2018   0           1           4           23-3-2018   9           2
27-3-2018   11          0           3           28-3-2018   0           1
01-4-2018   4           1           1           02-4-2018   6           1
```

Comment: Can you add what you want as a result?  That part isn't clear.

Comment: Do you want to add additional columns or just group the existing data?

Comment: I edited the question with an overview of the desired outcome.

Comment: @GeoffreyCelen given what the current Q post has. It is **NOT** an impossible task.. just need a little investment of keyboard, mouse and internet-ing.. mind sharing what you had tried but didn't/just partially work?   || You may include the *best* progress-made/tries(from Comment/links)/internet-search-results/screenshot/sampleFile into the Q post... Here are some of the examples [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720190/excel-interpolation-with-results-in-situ) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51449555/excel-sumifs-checking-if-a-column-contains-text/51451498)  .. (^_^)